# Sharepoint 2013 Current Navigation Home Link highlighted when on sub-page

Tags: 2013, current-navigation

[image]

On my SharePoint 2013 site, I have a series of links on the left hand Current Navigation menu.  One of the pages that can be accessed from this menu has additional links on it to sub pages that are not listed in the navigation menu on the left (and which I don't want to add to the menu).  Whenever someone goes to any of these sub pages, the "Home" link in the left hand navigation menu is highlighted by default.

Has anyone run across this issue before and if so, do you know how to resolve it?  I want it so that if one of the sub pages is viewed, NONE of the links in the left hand Current Navigation menu are highlighted.

Comment: Could you add some images of what is occurring with the snipping tool or screenshots? It'd be helpful to visualize the problem.

Comment: just added image to my original post.

Comment: Under Site Settings -> Navigation, what type of "Current Navigation" are you using? Ex. managed, structural, just trying to get a feel for your current settings.

Comment: I am using structural.

Comment: This link may be of use, it is talking about the Global Navigation (the links at the top of the page) but seems fairly applicable to the Current Navigation. : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d85e66c3-7e9f-44b4-902e-dfed8936e9f0/top-navigation-bar-highlight-problem?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy